# Undefined problem in group generator program in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a program that generate a random group of predefined names of students. the input is the number of groups desired to divide these students into. I have a problem in my code some of the names appear as undefined. Please can you help me?below is output sample
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Enter number of groups you want to divide your students:</label>
        <input type="number" id="number">
        <button type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
        <p id="names"></p>
    </form>
    <script src="name_generator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


function myFunction(){
    let studentNames=["Anas","Ahmad1","Akram","Abdulkader","AbdulMajeed","Osama","Anthony","Hasan","Basem","Basel","Bahaa","Nasir","Michel","Ahmad2","Zeinab","Bayan","Sandra","Tina","Karim","Ali", "Rudolf","Abdallah","Marwa","Mahmoud", "Malak","Rayan","Rania","Osama2"];
let y=document.getElementById("number").value;
let x= Math.floor(Math.random()*studentNames.length);
let w= studentNames.length;
let groupsNum= Math.ceil(w/y);
let groupList=[];
let groupID=0;


for (let i=0; i<y; i++){
    groupList.push([]);
}


for(let i= 0; i < w; i++) {

    groupList[groupID].push(studentNames[x]);
    studentNames.splice(x,1);
    groupID++;
    if(groupID >= y) {
      groupID = 0;
    }
  }

let generator = "";

  for(let i = 0; i < groupList.length; i++) {
    generator += "<P> <STRONG> GROUP " + (i+1) + "</strong></p><ol>";
    for(let j = 0; j < groupList[i].length; j++) {
        generator += "<li>"+ groupList[i][j]+ "</li>";
    }
    generator += "</ol>";
  }


  document.getElementById("names").innerHTML = generator;

}
```

Comment: An "undefined problem" could be "cannot read property of undefined", "variable x not defined", or the resultant HTML having an `undefined` in there somewhere, among other issues. It is not very clear what the problem is. Can you provide a sample of the incorrect output, or the full error text if there's an error?

Comment: [thank you for your answer. Actually i am new to web development, i am learning by myself some stuff and taking some online lectures. However it seems that the undefined problem isn't a variable that is undefined. i think its a coding mistake in a for loop in javascript.  for example when i enter the number of groups to divide the names. some of the names appear as undefined.

Comment: GROUP 1

    Ahmad2
    Sandra
    Ali
    Marwa
    Rayan
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined

GROUP 2

    Zeinab
    Tina
    Rudolf
    Mahmoud
    Rania
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined

like that

Comment: I suggest adding that info to the question as it's the most important part: "some of the names appear as undefined." and your sample output

Comment: Hi @AbdulkaderFreij,  first, as Klaycon said, you can try to be more clear with the title, the current one is pretty generic, second, good to know you are trying to learn something new, my recommendation is: try to understand the functions you are using, I said that because of the use of 'studentNames.splice(..)' it basically remove an element from an array and modifies his content, so every time your apply 'splice' you are changing the length of 'studentNames', that's the reason why you are getting undefined because your 'w' variable remains with the original length.

Comment: One solution is to recalculate x every time into this for:
for(let i= 0; i < w; i++) {

    groupList[groupID].push(studentNames[x]);
    studentNames.splice(x,1);
    groupID++;
    if(groupID >= y) {
      groupID = 0;
    }
 x= Math.floor(Math.random()*studentNames.length);
  }
with you are always playing with the current studentNames.length

Comment: @BryanAcuñaNúñez Thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: your welcome @AbdulkaderFreij, you can also explore the difference between 'let' and 'const' just to improve your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only assigning `x` to a random index in the array **once** and then it has the same value forever.

Thus when you keep executing `studentNames.splice(x,1);` with x not changing (since you never reassign it!) eventually you cut off all of the elements after `x` and trying to access `studentNames[x]` will get you `undefined` for all remaining iterations.

For example say the array has 30 student names and `x` is randomly selected to be 20, and then it never changes from 20. So you keep accessing `studentNames[20]` and removing the 20th element. You remove 10 elements and then `studentNames[20]` will just be `undefined`.

Reassign `x` to a new random index in the loop:

```
for(let i= 0; i < w; i++) {
    groupList[groupID].push(studentNames[x]);
    studentNames.splice(x,1);
    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*studentNames.length);
    groupID++;
    if(groupID >= y) {
      groupID = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @AbdulkaderFreij I'm glad you found the answer helpful. If it solved your problem, feel free to hit the checkmark to let other readers know it is a working answer to the question.